# Approximating simple functions by "nice" simple functions in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, simple-functions

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ be bounded. Let $S$ be the set of simple functions defined on $\Omega$, and let $M\subset S$ be the set of simple functions whose defining sets can be written as finite unions of rectangles in $\Omega$. The question: Is $M$ dense in $S$ in the $L^2(\Omega)$ sense?

If this is not true, let $L\subset S$ be the set of simple functions whose defining sets $E_j$ satisfy $m(\partial E_j)=0$ ($m$ here the Lebesgue measure). Is $L$ dense in $S$ in the $L^2(\Omega)$ sense?

Thanks for your input!

EDIT: Here's what I've been trying to do, for what it's worth: Fix a simple function $s\in S$, with defining sets $E_1,\ldots,E_m$ and written as
$$
s(x)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^ma_j\chi_{E_j}(x).
$$
Each of these sets is Lebesgue measurable, so for each $j=1,\ldots,m$ and $n\in\mathbb N$ you can find a set $A_j^n\subset\Omega$ which is a finite union of rectangles in $\Omega$ and satisfies
$$
m(E_j\Delta A_j^n)<2^{-n}.
$$
For fixed $n$ now, construct a simple function $s_n$ in the following way: For each $j=1,\ldots,m$, let $E_j^n=A_j^n\backslash\bigcup_{\ell\neq j}A_{\ell}^n$; and $E_{m+1}^n=\Omega\backslash\bigcup_{j}E_j^n$. Let $a_{m+1}=0$. Then write
$$
s_n(x)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m+1}a_j\chi_{E_j^n}(x).
$$
We have $s_n\in M$ for each $n$. After an elementary calculation it is seen that
$$
\Vert s-s_n\Vert_{L_2(\Omega)}^2\leq C\sum\limits_{j=1}^mm(E_j\Delta E_j^n)
$$
where $C$ is a constant depending on $D$ and $s$. What I'm trying to prove will be given as soon as I can replace $E_j^n$ with $A_j^n$ in the above inequality. This, in turn, is done "if and only if" I can suitably estimate the measure of the "intersections" between the $A_{\ell}^n$, but it's not clear to me how to do this.

Comment: you can argue that the continuous functions are dense in $L^2(\Omega)$, and that the simple functions are dense in the continuous functions for the $L^2$ norm

Comment: I know that, but that does not seem to help in answering my question, unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: what I mean is that "to be dense" is transitive, so as usual it reduces to showing $L^2(\Omega) :$ the $|.|^2$ Lebesgue integrable functions is the same as $L^2(\Omega) :$ the closure of the continuous functions for the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: Ah, of course; the problem will be solved if we can show that functions in $M$ approximate any old $L_2(\Omega)$ function. I phrased the problem as I did because I believe the present formulation is basically what needs to be proved to obtain the more "general" result.

Comment: Are the elements of $S$ assumed to be integrable? Note that $\sigma ( {\cal R} ) = {\cal B}$ (collection of rectangles and Borel sets, respectively).

Comment: I don't get your problem, if for any $\chi_{E_j}$ you have an $\epsilon$ approximation with rectangles, then for $\sum_{j=1}^m a_j \chi_{E_j}$ you have an $ \epsilon\sum_{j=1}^m |a_j|$ approximation with rectangles

Comment: @copper.hat yes, assume that $S\subset L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: @user1952009 When I go from the $A_j^n$s to the $E_j^n$s, I am getting rid of all possible intersections between the $A_j^n$, and I clump them all up on $E_{m+1}^n$. But a priori there seems to be no guarantee that the measure of the set $E_{m+1}^n$ approaches $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Consider fat Cantor-like sets, for example, which have no interior and their boundary has positive measure.

Comment: Some further clarification: The intersections of the $A_j^n$s basically "cover-up" the boundaries of the $E_j$s, and if the measure of these boundaries is positive then the measure of the intersections of the $A_j^n$s cannot drop to $0$.

Comment: the keyword is "finite sum"

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather tedious solution:

Suppose $S \subset L^2(\Omega)$. The set $\Omega$ is bounded.

Let $s \in S$, then we can write $s = \sum_k \alpha_k 1_{A_k}$.

Note that any open set $U$ can be written as the countable union of disjoint rectangles $U = \cup_k R_k$. We see that $m({\cup_{i=0}^n R_i}) \to m U$.

For any $\epsilon>0 $ there is an open set $U_k$ containing $A_k$ such that $m(U_k \setminus A_k) < \epsilon$ (outer regularity).

It follows that for any $\epsilon>0 $ there is a finite collection of
rectangles $B_k = \cup_{i=0}^{n_k} R_{i,k}$ such that $m(B_k \triangle A_k) < \epsilon$.
Note that $\|1_{B_k} - 1_{A_k}\| \le \sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Then $\|s-\sum_k \alpha_k 1_{B_k} \| \le \sum_k |\alpha_k| \sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Thank you for this. But I have a question though: How do you know that the $B_k$s are disjoint? I think this difficulty is the same one that I encountered in my attempt...

Comment: @Lentes: I will edit the disjoint parts out, it is not used anywhere above except for the inner approximation of open $U$ by rectangles.

Comment: Thank you, I see where I was getting stuck now. I was interpreting the definition of a simple function too rigidly. As long as the number of defining sets is finite (as it is for a simple function), it doesn't matter if they are disjoint or not.

Comment: @Lentes: Usually the disjointedness is a convenience. In the above, one could choose $B_k'$ disjoint (and appropriately changed $\alpha_k'$) such that $\sum_k \alpha_k 1_{B_k} = \sum_k \alpha_k' 1_{B_k'}$ but it is a nuisance with no value (the $\sum$ may be over a different range, I was too lazy to typeset it properly.).